# javascript onmouseout clear html element

Tags: javascript, navigation, onmouseover, onmouseout

I am trying to figure out how to clear the contents of a specific HTML ID on a JavaScript onmouseleave event. My onmouseover works perfectly fine but onmouseout doesn't.

This is a navigation bar (work in progress) so when the user hovers their mouse over a header, it will then expose the sub links but when they leave that menu, it should close.

Everything that i've reseached has led me to nothing...I'm looking for hints on how to complete the onmouseout function for this scenario.

Thanks!

Here's what I've got:

```
     document.getElementById('theHeaderTag1').onmouseover = function () {
    for (var i = 0; i <= Level1Items.length - 1; i++) {
        //Print Items in Level1
        var createLevel1CellTag = document.createElement('tr');
        createLevel1CellTag.id = 'Level1';
        var Level1TextNode = document.createTextNode(Level1Items[i]);
        createLevel1CellTag.appendChild(Level1TextNode);
        document.getElementById('theHeaderTag0').appendChild(createLevel1CellTag);
    }
    document.getElementById('theHeaderTag1').onmouseout = function () {

    }
```

I have a feeling that I'm going to run into issues with this though...but I think this will put me on the right track.

Here's all the code:

```
var siteUrl = '/sites/dev/';
var theCounter = 0;
ExecuteOrDelayUntilScriptLoaded(retrieveListItems, "sp.js");

function retrieveListItems() {
var clientContext = new SP.ClientContext(siteUrl);
var oList = clientContext.get_web().get_lists().getByTitle('myList');
var camlQuery = new SP.CamlQuery();
camlQuery.set_viewXml("<Where><And><IsNotNull><FieldRef Name='Title' /></IsNotNull> <IsNotNull><FieldRef Name='TitleLink' /></IsNotNull></And></Where>");
this.collListItem = oList.getItems(camlQuery);
clientContext.load(collListItem);
clientContext.executeQueryAsync(Function.createDelegate(this, this.onQuerySucceeded),  Function.createDelegate(this, this.onQueryFailed));
 }


//Where all the magic happens
function onQuerySucceeded(sender, args) {

//Create an Array for each column in the SharePoint List that will be used in the NavPart
var theHeaders = new Array();
var HeaderLinks = new Array();
var Level1Items = new Array();
var getTheTableTag = document.getElementById('theTable');

var listItemEnumerator = collListItem.getEnumerator();

while (listItemEnumerator.moveNext()) {
    var oListItem = listItemEnumerator.get_current();
    theCounter += 1;

    //Build an Array for the column elements.
    theHeaders[theCounter - 1] = oListItem.get_item('Title');
    Level1Items[theCounter - 1] = oListItem.get_item('Level1');



};
var headersResult = _.uniq(theHeaders);
var headerLinkResult = _.uniq(HeaderLinks);

//Create Headers on the Web Part
for (var i = 0; i <= headersResult.length - 1; i++) {
    var createTheHeaderTag = document.createElement('th');
    createTheHeaderTag.id = 'theHeaderTag' + i;
    var TheHeaderTagTextNode = document.createTextNode(headersResult[i]);
    createTheHeaderTag.appendChild(TheHeaderTagTextNode);
    getTheTableTag.appendChild(createTheHeaderTag);


}

document.getElementById('theHeaderTag1').onmouseover = function () {
    for (var i = 0; i <= Level1Items.length - 1; i++) {
        //Print Items in Level1
        var createLevel1CellTag = document.createElement('tr');
        createLevel1CellTag.id = 'Level1';
        var Level1TextNode = document.createTextNode(Level1Items[i]);
        createLevel1CellTag.appendChild(Level1TextNode);
        document.getElementById('theHeaderTag0').appendChild(createLevel1CellTag);
    }
    document.getElementById('theHeaderTag1').onmouseout = function () {

    }
}
}
function onQueryFailed(sender, args) {
alert('Request failed. ' + args.get_message() + '\n' + args.get_stackTrace());
}
```

Comment: You can give jQuery a chance...

Answer (score 1):

The Code looks fine. You need to remove or hide the DOM elements on mouseout.

EDIT-> Demo : http://jsfiddle.net/uENE7/

```
document.getElementById('theHeaderTag1').onmouseout = function () {
   document.getElementById('theHeaderTag0').removeChild("Level1")
}
```

To check whether your mouseout event is triggered, please add a console log message.

```
document.getElementById('theHeaderTag1').onmouseout = function () {
   console.log("mouseout event triggered");
   document.getElementById('theHeaderTag0').removeChild("Level1");
}
```

Comment: can you please copy paste the exact error message. I want to know which line is throwing that error.

Comment: the error should be on removeChild. The parameter is the id to be removed inside the DOM node "theHeaderTag0". https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Node.removeChild

Comment: Line 62:             document.getElementById('theHeaderTag0').removeChild()

Comment: I get a "type mismatch" error when I try and pass the parameter `theHeaderTag0`

Comment: I have created a jsfiddle for it. It works there http://jsfiddle.net/uENE7/. There is a minor bug in your code. You are assigning same id to all tr elements. You should class.